# Remove first set of double br only, convert other double br to single br

Tags: jquery, html

I have html that is being pulled in from an external source. The problem is that I want to target double `br` with `jQuery`, so that I can remove the first double `br` entirely and convert all of the rest of the double `br` to single `br`.

The html looks like the following:

```
<div class="bottom-paragraph-drop">
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

jQuery:

Not sure what to do; something along the lines of

`$('.bottom-paragraph-drop br').next('br').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Given the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Do It">
<div class="bottom-paragraph-drop">
  <br />
  <br /> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy
  text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <br />
  <br /> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

You can eliminate the second break tag by iterating over the break tags in the div and testing if the next element is a break (and then remove the element):

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  $('div br').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is('br')) {
      $(this).next().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/q3z7099s/).

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the br elements and remove the first two, and then brs that are alternating in index as such -

```
function test() {
  $('br')[0].remove();
  $('br')[1].remove();
  for(var i = 2; i<$('br').length; i+=2) {
    $('br')[i].remove();
  }
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegularExpression to target these br elements:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.bottom-paragraph-drop');
var text = div.innerHTML;
var result = text.replace(/^\s*<br>\s*<br>/, "").replace(/<br>\s*<br>/g, "<br>");
div.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div class="bottom-paragraph-drop">
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    <br>
    <br>
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

Or, if you want to target also 'self closed' tags your regexp could look like that:

`/<br\s*\/*>\s*<br\s*\/*>/`